# AJAX dont call WebMethod but returns HTML

Tags: ajax, webmethod

I had read a lot of questions here on Stackoverflow about AJAX calls to WebMethods, and I tried a lot of things and nothing works.

My AJAX method doesnt call the WebMethod on server side but returns success and the entire HTML of the page.

This is the AJAX:

```
$("[id*=butLogin]").click(function () {
            var obj = {};
            obj.pEmail = "EMAIL"; //$.trim($("[id*=txtName]").val());
            obj.pPassword = "PASSWORD"; //$.trim($("[id*=txtAge]").val());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.aspx/logOn",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg, merr, derr) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

And this is the WebMethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string logOn(string pEmail, string pPassword)
    {
        return "logged";
    }
```

I believe is a simples mistake.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post your web.config file ? are you using friendlyURL feature?

Comment: check if you have this in your web.config modules `<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>`

Comment: What is the version of .NET?

Comment: Im using .NET 3.5, and this is the webconfig:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" >

        </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>

Comment: I tried the ScriptModule you mentioned, but, the application dindt work.